# How read 3 fields from a text file and write it in single line?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to read 3 values like "IP","port","name" from the sample.txt and print like "IP+port+name" using given python code below:

Sample.txt:

```
device.IP=172.2.1.5
test1.name=m1234-tsample.test.com
input.port$test=2233
userName=test@test1.com
passwd=test123
nmae=ryan
```

test.py:

```
import re

def change_port():
    with open('/Users/test/Desktop/sample.txt', 'rt') as in_file:
        contents = in_file.read()
        result   = re.compile(r'%s.*?%s' % ("IP=", "test1.name="), re.S)
        IP=result.search(contents).group(0)
        result1   = re.compile(r'%s.*?%s' % ("port$test=", "userName"), re.S)
        port= result1.search(contents).group(1)
        result2   = re.compile(r'%s.*?%s' % ("test1.name=", "input.port$test"), re.S)
        name= result2.search(contents).group(2)
        print name+IP+port

change_port()
```

But I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    change_port()
  File "test.py", line 7, in change_port
    IP=result.search(contents).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Could anyone give a clue to fix this please?

Comment: Escape `$` and `.` Also, capture `.*?` -> `(.*?)` and get `.group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex.

**demo**

```
s = """device.IP=172.2.1.5
test1.name=m1234-tsample.test.com
input.port$test=2233
userName=test@test1.com
passwd=test123
nmae=ryan"""

IP, port, name = "", "", ""
for i in s.split("\n"):
    if "IP" in i:
        IP = i.split("=")[-1]
    if "port" in i:
        port = i.split("=")[-1]
    if "userName" in i:
        name = i.split("=")[-1]
print "IP:{}, Port:{}, Name:{}".format(IP, port, name)
```

**Output:**

```
IP:172.2.1.5, Port:2233, Name:test@test1.com
```